# Writing full html page into iframe without document.write()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating an iframe dynamically using jquery, and I want to know if there is a way to write a full html page (html string response from an ajax request) into it without using the `document.write()` operation.

Since I'm starting off with an empty iframe the `$.find().html()` or `innerHTML()` methods are not going to work here. Also, `iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);` doesn't work in all browsers.

Iframe:

```
  var myIframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                    id: 'my-iframe',
                    name: 'my-iframe',
                    src: 'about:blank',
                    scrolling: 'no',
                    frameborder: 0,
                    style: 'width: 224px; height: 230px;'
                });
```

Comment: What do you want to load/"show" in the iframe? Do you have the whole content in form of a JS string variable? Or where else does it originate?

Comment: It's an html string response from an ajax request.

Comment: And the request method/content is? A simple GET request you could make by simply assigning the URL to the iframe's src attribute, and for a POST request a simple form `target`ing the iframe could do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? After the iframe has been added to the parent document

```
// Edit 
myIframe.contents().find("body").html("My new content")

// Log
console.log(myIframe.contents().find("body").html())
```

Comment: How's that going to help? This will just add to the body. I have lots of header tags and also classes and properties in my 'html' tag

Comment: I probably don't understand your question.. Did you try to get access to iframe content from the parent document ?

Comment: I am trying to access the iframe from the parent document. The html that I'm trying to render is a string response from an ajax request. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function of jquery and load an html page into the iframe.. like this:

```
$( "#my-iframe" ).load( "./path/to/the/html/file.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```